# Django + PostgreSQL + DjangoRestFramework

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlalchemy, django-rest-framework

I've found there is a model framework for PostgreSQL:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property
from ..base import Base

class Staff(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'account'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = column_property(Column(String(30), nullable=False))
    surname = column_property(Column(String(30)))
    otch = column_property(Column(String(30), nullable=False))
    b_date = column_property(Column(String(30)))
    pol = column_property(Column(String(3), nullable=False))
    email = column_property(Column(String(100)))
    gruppa = column_property(Column(String(30), nullable=False))
    fak = column_property(Column(String(30)))
    profile = column_property(Column(String(30), nullable=False))
```

There is a view that through a serializater must give details:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    session = request.sa_session
    h = session.query(Staff).all()
    for i in h:
        print i.name
    serializer = TaskSerializer(h, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Description TaskSerializer:

```
from db.admin.db import Staff
from rest_framework import serializers

class TaskSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Staff
```

But when you run, there is an error:

> type object 'Staff' has no attribute '_meta'

The joke is that if the model is built through `Model.model`:

```
from django.db import models

class Staff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    otch = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    b_date = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pol = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gruppa = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    fak = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    profile = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

it all works.

Is it possible to use SQLAlchemy model or only Django's `models.Model`?

Answer (score 1):

The Django REST Framework only supports Django ORM with its `ModelSerializer`s. Since you are using SQAlchemy, you will not be able to use any of that goodness.

**DEPRECATED** (see below for new suggestion) - There is a library which attempts to add support for SQAlchemy to DRF - [DjangoREST Alchemy](https://github.com/dealertrack/djangorest-alchemy). Full disclosure - I know the author who is a coworker. It however only does the read-only operations, so it will not support all the features DRF supports for Django ORM. You are more than welcome though to open issues and/or contribute!

**EDIT 04/19** - DjangoREST Alchemy is deprecated. Would recommend to take a look at either [django-sorcery](https://django-sorcery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [django-rest-witchcraft](https://django-rest-witchcraft.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). They achieve much better DRF integration while making it feel as if you are working with Django ORM.

Comment: I so understand this library not относитя to rest in any way, and simply independent?
whether SQlAlchemy can be transferred to Model somehow?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to transform SQLAlchemy model to Django ORM model and that would seem like a bad idea for other reasons (e.g. how both manage db sessions, etc). Instead of transforming models between 2 ORMs, it is better to create utilities to transform a model to a serializer directly.

Comment: how to transform model to the serializer?

Comment: Look at the library I linked to. It has some facilities to do that

Comment: you can write approximately as the serilizator will look, and I not absolutely understand that